# JSON dictionaries to Pandas DataFrame in Python

Tags: json, python-2.7, pandas

I get JSON data from an API service, and I would like to use a DataFrame to then output the data into CSV.

So, I am trying to convert a list of dictionaries, with about 100.000 dictionaries with about 100 key value pairs, nested up to 4 levels deep, into a Pandas DataFrame.

I am using the following code, but it is painfully slow:

```
try:
    # Convert each JSON data event to a Pandas DataFrame
    df_i = []
    for d in data:
        df_i.append( json_normalize(d) )

    # Concatenate all DataFrames into a single one
    df = concat(df_i, axis=0)

except AttributeError:
    print "Error: Expected a list of dictionaries to parse JSON data"
```

Does anyone know of a better and faster way to do this?

Comment: pandas can read json directly: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.read_json.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [whole section in the io docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#reading-json) on reading json (as strings or files) directly using `pd.read_json`.

You ought to be able to do something like:

```
pd.concat((pd.read_json(d) for d in data), axis=0)
```

*This will often be much faster than creating a temporary dict.*

Comment: Thank you. Given that the json format I have is nested, it was not parsed correctly by read_json(), giving me a TypeError. However, I used your form with json_normalize():`df = concat((json_normalize(d) for d in data), axis=0)`

Answer (score 2):

The following example founded in pandas.io.json.json_normalize documentation (link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
>>> from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
>>> data = [{'id': 1, 'name': {'first': 'Coleen', 'last': 'Volk'}},
        {'name': {'given': 'Mose', 'family': 'Regner'}},
        {'id': 2, 'name': 'Faye Raker'}]
>>> json_normalize(data)
   id        name name.family name.first name.given name.last
0  1.0         NaN         NaN     Coleen        NaN      Volk
1  NaN         NaN      Regner        NaN       Mose       NaN
2  2.0  Faye Raker         NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN
```